# How to solve the error 'Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and trying to implement a reactjs application by following tutorials in [Fullstack.io](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/react-tutorial-cloning-yelp/). When I got to the middle of this tutorial, I received the error while running `npm run test`.

**app.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'


import App from 'containers/App/App'

import './app.css'

import {browserHistory, Router, Route} from 'react-router'

const Home = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>Hello world</div>)
  }
})

const routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  </Router>
)



const mountNode = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(
  <App history={browserHistory} />, mountNode);
```

App.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom' 
import { Router } from 'react-router'; 
class App extends React.Component { 
   static propTypes = { 
      routes: PropTypes.object.isRequired, 
      history: PropTypes.object.isRequired 
   }
   get content() { 
       return (
            <Router routes={this.props.routes} history={this.props.history} />
        ) 
    } 
    render() { 
       return ( 
          <div style={ { height: '100%' } }> {this.content} </div>
        ) 
    }
  } 
export default App;
```

I couldn't find out where the error is, can anyone help me solve the issue?

The screenshot of error is given below:
[image: error image]

Comment: what do you have in your `<App>` component

Comment: Inside containers/App folder there is three files. App.js, App.spec.js, styles.module.css and App.js is as follows import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router } from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    routes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }  get content() {    return (<Router       routes={this.props.routes}      history={this.props.history} />) }  render() {    return (  <div style={ { height: '100%' } }>
        {this.content}   </div>    ) }}

Comment: do you have two app.js files and I think you are not exporting your App component that is the problem

Comment: I missd code export default App; while posting question. it is there in actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You are not exporting your `App` component.

Change it to

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom' 
import { Router } from 'react-router'; 
export default class App extends React.Component { 
   static propTypes = { 
      routes: PropTypes.object.isRequired, 
      history: PropTypes.object.isRequired 
   }
   get content() { 
       return (
            <Router routes={this.props.routes} history={this.props.history} />
        ) 
    } 
    render() { 
       return ( 
          <div style={ { height: '100%' } }> {this.content} </div>
        ) 
    }
  }
```

Notice the `export` keyword.

Comment: in bottom of my code there is export default App; . Also I have changed as per your suggestion.. But still the issue exists